# Removing lockring/ cups off head tube on vintage BSA bike

Tags: bottom-bracket, headset

I finally managed to get the **SOB** crank arms off the bike. It took a spare seat post and 100mm enginners vice, and perseverance.

Anyway I'm on the home striaght now in terms of getting the bloody thingy painted finally.

I want to know what tools I need to remove the BB and the cups off the head tube?

Here are some photos of what am talking about

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to loosen the locknut on that right-side BB cup before you try to remove it.

Comment: oh whys that?  As much as I like the original BSA chainring,  since I can't get a cotter pin press in the uk, I think I'm going to convert it to a square taper. I probably get my LBS to do it for me, that way I'm not messing around

Comment: Why remove the headset cups ?   Are you blasting/painting the frame?

Comment: yes! I am using an industrial power coating company to do it because the proper bike restoring places are charging £290 - 300 plus P&P. Hence I doubt they would care for my cups.  I already have had a few challenges and there is still the BB. I dont want to have to replace the cups as well

Comment: @Ageis - Loosening the locknut is kinda required for any BB design, if locknuts are employed at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Park HCW-11 wrench to remove/adjust the BB cups:

https://www.parktool.com/product/adjustable-cup-wrench-hcw-11

RT-1 to remove the headset cups:

https://www.parktool.com/product/head-cup-remover-rt-1

or just a long flat head screwdriver and hammer to gently tap them out.

Comment: oh btw the way so on the drive side I willbe turning clockwise to remove yes? Then on non drive it's actually rhd threaded so lefty loosey

Comment: On british bikes, yes, you'll loosen by turning towards the front of the bike. drive side clockwise, NDS counterclockwise.

Comment: Yes - general rule is that the left pedal and right side of BB are reverse-threaded.  Unless its exotic/french/italian.